# PetaPoco test for Existance

Tags: petapoco

Looking through the documentation for PetaPoco

https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/wiki/Querying-LINQ-Style

Specifically:

```
result = db.Exist<Person>("WHERE Id = @0", 12);
```

A couple of problems:

1) the method "Exist" doesn't exist on my version. PetaPoco is bundled with Umbraco v7.7.7 so it may be an old version. Lets suppose its a typo.

2) The "Exists" method only takes one parameter (the PK) so my compiler doesn't like this syntax.

It looks like this method only accepts an Int PK as a parameter

This works fine but I don't want to use the PK (which doesn't exist yet) as a parameter

```
var result = db.Exists<Person>(12);
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: You could write a query and execute it, or just fetch and see if you get a result?

Comment: Agree and I bet I'll end up doing that, but I am rather disappointed the method doesn't work as described.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out and thought I'd share:

instead of...

```
bool result = db.Exist<Person>("WHERE Id = @0", 12);
```

Use...

```
bool result = db.Fetch<Person>("WHERE id=@0", 12).Any();
```

a bit of a clunk but there you have it.

Comment: You can add your own extension method to do `.Exist` if you want

Comment: Sure, my point was the method allegedly had one already. It won't be the last time that happens.